# Is there a concise way to output the same string to both a file and the console?

Tags: c#

If I want to output something to both a file and the console, shall i do the two things separately in two statements, or is there a more succinct way for example, one statement for writing to both the file and console?

For example

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
...
file.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
...
file.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
...
file.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
...
file.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(...) + string.Format(...));
...
file.Close();
```

the arguments to the calls to `string.Format()` are complicated and long.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the strings the same for each call to `file.WriteLine()` and `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: Usually we create a Log class that will output to both, and then call `Log.Write(...)`

Comment: @maccettura: for each pair, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Write a <s>function</s>method that does both. Put it in a class that has a file stream or whatever and keep a copy around.

```
public void Write(string fmt, params object[] args) {
    var str = String.Format(fmt, args);
    _file.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

If you're using C#6, give that method a single string parameter and use interpolation instead of `String.Format()` arguments:

```
public void Write(string str) {
    _file.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

...

```
_log.Write($"My {vehicle} is full of {seaCreature}s, it is {damageDescription}");
```

I prefer interpolation for readability ("Wait, what was `{0}` again?") and because I recall the `params object[]` method stuff can get tricky with overload resolution. It's been a couple of years but I can dig up the details if there's any interest. But think about it, anything can be an object, and you can have one or more arguments, and sometimes it all ends in tears.

Comment: Thanks. Why  use interpolation instead of String.Format() arguments:?

Comment: @Tim Because I prefer it for readability (/opinion), and because IIRC `params object[]` method overloads can be tricky with overload resolution, which I wimped out on going into because I haven't done it in a while.